# PHP Button Custom link

Tags: custom-post-types, php, permalinks, templates, links

At this part of code of a wp template I want to change the permalink url of the "Book Now" button to custom link example: "www.mywebsite.com"

```
byt_render_field("description clearfix", "", "", $accommodation_description_html, '', false, true);
if (!empty($current_url) && $current_url == $list_user_accommodations_url)
    byt_render_link_button($submit_accommodations_url . '?fesid=' . $accommodation_id, "gradient-button clearfix", "", __('Edit', 'bookyourtravel')); 
else 
    byt_render_link_button($accommodation_obj->get_permalink(), "gradient-button clearfix", "", __('Book now', 'bookyourtravel'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what `byt_render_link_button()` does, but I try this.

```
<?php 
byt_render_field("description clearfix", "", "", $accommodation_description_html, '', false, true);
if (!empty($current_url) && $current_url == $list_user_accommodations_url) {
     byt_render_link_button($submit_accommodations_url . '?fesid=' . $accommodation_id, "gradient-button clearfix", "", __('Edit', 'bookyourtravel'));   
} else {
     byt_render_link_button( 'http://www.mywebsite.com', "gradient-button clearfix", "", __('Book now', 'bookyourtravel') );
}
```